# Make toggle behave like input controls i.e. to respond to space bar key down and keyboard tab action

Tags: css, html

We have toggle controls as in the below link
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp
While these take input on mouse click, they don't change state on space key down and when keyboard tab is used these are not highlighted/selected.

How can these be made behave like any regular input control?

I would look for solution in html/css which could be easily applied to any such controls.

Update:
As mentioned in the answer, checkboxes change state on press of spacebar and not enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with css. Since we have to guess how your html and css is structured, i can only provide you something you can work with.

And by the way you change checkbox state with spacebar, not with enter key

```css
label { margin-right: 1rem }
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: rebeccapurple
}

input:focus + label span {
  outline: 1px solid red
}

input:checked + label span {
  background: red
}

/* https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/ */

.visuallyhidden {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="check" class="visuallyhidden" type="checkbox">
<label for="check"><span></span></label>


<input id="box" class="visuallyhidden" type="checkbox">
<label for="box"><span></span></label>
```

Comment: Good solution however the mouse click does not work now which was working in the example. html structure is same as given in the example in the link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: @Satyajit yeah you're right. Check out the edited code. Moved the spans inside labels and now they should work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. First add a tab index to the element, so it can be focused. Then you can add this jQuery code.

```
$('.switch').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        if($(this).children("input").attr('checked')) {
            $(this).children("input").attr('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(this).children("input").attr('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

I edited the code W3Schools site to add this code. You can view it at https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHPJRINMFQOH.

Good Luck!! Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -1):

This can done using jquery

Since the toggle button is a simple checkbox we can access them using the keypress function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#mycheckbox').keypress(function(event) {
                var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

                if (keycode == 13) {
                    clickCheckBox(this);
                }   
                event.stopPropagation();
            });             
        });

        function clickCheckBox(box){

                var $box = $(box); 
                    $box.prop('checked',!$box.prop('checked')); 

        }
```

find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kuladeep/gk87o3be/)